# Merging data frame based on common variables and minimum distance

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 data sets `V =`

```
id A B X
1 a b 10
2 a b 9
3 b c 8
4 b d 17
```

and `W =`

```
ud A B Y
11 a b 11
12 a b 7
13 b c 8
14 b d 21
```

and I want to merge them. Using `dplyr`s join functions the code is

```
merge = V %>% inner_join(W, by = c("A", "B"))
```

and the result is

```
 id    ud A     B         X     Y
 1     11 a     b      10.0  11.0 
 1     12 a     b      10.0   7.00
 2     11 a     b      9.00  11.0 
 2     12 a     b      9.00   7.00
 3     13 b     c      8.00   8.00
 4     14 b     d     17.0   21.0
```

Due to the inner join, combinations of the matches were returned. However, I want a (unique) correspondence between the two identifier variables `id` and `ud` (here this is not the case because for example 1 is mapped to 11 AND 12). 
I want to create this unique correspondence by assigning that `id` to `ud` for which `d(X,Y)` is minimal, using some distance function (e.g. `d(x,y) = abs(x-y)`).

But how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below?

```
V %>% inner_join(W, by = c("A", "B")) %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(which.min(abs(X - Y)))
```

Output:

```
     id A     B         X    ud     Y
  <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 a     b        10    11    11
2     2 a     b         9    11    11
3     3 b     c         8    13     8
4     4 b     d        17    14    21
```